# How can I see what Xml does the WCF RESTful service return?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, service

I want to ask how can i see what xml does the WCF RESTful return.
I build it and implemented it on my asp.net site and it works perfectly but when I try to access it from the browser it doesn't return anything.

Here is how I defined one of the methods in the IRESTful interface:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GEO_OBJECTS", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
[OperationContract]
IEnumerable<GEO_OBJECT> GetAll();
```

and this is how I'm accessing it from my browser:

`http://localhost:49504/Diplomska/RESTful.svc/GEO_OBJECTS/GetAll`

So what am I doing wrong here?
I hosted it on IIS7 (on my local machine), it does the same thing.
the service and the web site are in the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Chrome Extension [Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb) you can use to more easily test out RESTful web services.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try using Fiddler and pay attention to the responses coming in over the wire.

Comment: You are under-selling Fiddler: Fiddler 2 includes a request builder that allows you to build your own requests, which easily allows you to test REST services.

Comment: Very true.  I didn't mention that.  Thanks for the catch!